# How to convert a [Int] to [Int] on haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to receive a list [Int] and calculate the value of the elements and return a list with the sum value. But if the sum value > 9 the list will be (example) [5,6]. But if not < 10 the list will be (example) [0,9]
I have done it and doesn't work

```
size_list :: [Int] -> Int
size_list [] = 0
size_list (x:xs) = x + size_list xs

digitVerify :: [Int] -> [Int]
digitVerify [] = []
digitVerify l = if ((size_list l) > 9)
                     then
                     (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10)
                     else
                     0 : (size_list l)
```

Comment: A two element list is written as `[x,y]` (or `x:y:[]`), not as `x:y`.

Comment: I managed to solve like this

 
 digitVerify :: [Int] -> [Int]
 digitVerify [] = []
 digitVerify l = if ((size_list l) > 9)
                         then
                         [(div (size_list l) 10)] ++ [(mod (size_list l) 10)]
                         else
                         [0] ++ [(size_list l)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The second parameter of the `:` has to be a list even if empty `[]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.10/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:cons).

Error: `0 : 3`
`[0,3]`: `0 : 3 : []`

```
size_list :: [Int] -> Int
size_list [] = 0
size_list (x:xs) = x + size_list xs

digitVerify :: [Int] -> [Int]
digitVerify [] = []
digitVerify l = if ((size_list l) > 9)
                     then
                     (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10) : []
                     else
                     0 : (size_list l) : []
```

Test:

```
digitVerify [3]
digitVerify [50,6]
```

Output:

```
[0,3]
[50,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

Compiling the code in question throws the following errors, which are two instances of the same thing:

```
fold.hs:9:48: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(mod (size_list l) 10)’
      In the expression: (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10)
      In the expression:
        if ((size_list l) > 9) then
            (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10)
        else
            0 : (size_list l)
  |
9 |                      (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10)
  |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

fold.hs:11:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(size_list l)’
      In the expression: 0 : (size_list l)
      In the expression:
        if ((size_list l) > 9) then
            (div (size_list l) 10) : (mod (size_list l) 10)
        else
            0 : (size_list l)
   |
11 |                      0 : (size_list l)
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is this?

Taking the first example, you are calling the operator `:` to create your list, with two arguments: `div (size_list l) 10` and `mod (size_list l) 10`. (`:` is actually syntax sugar for a constructor, not a function, but we can ignore this distincton in this case.)

What is the type of `:`?

A GHCi session tells us:

```
Prelude> :type (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

`(:)` takes a value of type `a` and a *list* of `a`s, and returns a list of `a`s, which is the second argument with the first argument prepended to it.

Because you passed an `Int` as the first argument, GHC expects a `[Int]` as the second argument, but you've given it an `Int`, hence the error.

Instead, to create a two-element list like this, you have a number of options:

- Use the list literal syntax:

  ```
  [div (size_list l) 10, mod (size_list l) 10]
  ```
- Use the `:` operator associatively, but put the empty list at the end of the chain:

  ```
  div (size_list l) 10 : mod (size_list l) 10 : []
  ```

  `:` associates right, so this is the equivalent of

  ```
  div (size_list l) 10 : (mod (size_list l) 10 : [])
  ```

  which is valid, if you think about it.
- Concatenate singleton lists:

  ```
  [div (size_list l) 10] ++ [mod (size_list l) 10]
  ```

However, since this function always returns a two-element list, it's probably more appropriate for it to return a tuple, i.e. `digitVerify` should have the type `[Int] -> (Int, Int)`.

I'll leave you to explore that option, if you get stuck you can just come back and ask another question.

Happy Haskelling!